# virtualbox dns says "unknown host" Win7 host/ubuntu guest

Tags: ubuntu, dns, virtualbox

virtualbox dns says "unknown host" Win7 host/ubuntu guest

My PC runs Windows 7 and I have installed Virtualbox.

In virtualbox I have configured a virtual Ubuntu 12 machine.

When I run nm-tool in Ubuntu, it lists my local home router 192.168.N.M as the DNS server and I can ping this IP address. I can also ping 4.2.2.2 from the virtual Ubuntu.

My Windows 7 host OS has the same DNS server and it works fine.

The difference between the guest and the host OS is in the Gateway. My host OS has 192.168.N.M as the Gateway, but the virtual Ubuntu says 10.0.2.2.

In /etc/hosts it says:

"nameserver 127.0.0.1" but also warnings that I should not edit this file as edits will be overwritten.

Why is /etc/resolv.conf and nm-tool in disagreement about the DNS server address and how do I remedy this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to change the Virtualbox network router setting for this virtual machine from "NAT" to "Bridged Connection".

The /etc/resolv.conf file will then say

nameserver 127.0.0.1
search router

and things work.

(got this info from forums.virtualbox.org)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but still...

- Open Virtual Box if not opened
- Then look at the top Menu bar
- Then click Machine from Menu bar and then click Settings
- Then Click Network Now you see Network settings on the right side of the panel
- Select Bridged Adapter in the Attached to: drop down list

Give it a few sec and then do a ping again or open FireFox and go to www.google.com

It worked for me.